# Authentication error when pushing to remote Git repo with TortoiseGit

Tags: git, msysgit, tortoisegit

When I try an push to my remote repo (Unfuddle) using TortoiseGit, my favourite tool, I get the following error.  I then open GitGUI and am able to push with no problem.  I have gathered through some googling that pageant needs to be running for some PuTTY variants, and it is running.  Where do I look next?

*No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)*

Comment: Did you ever find a solution here? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Resetting the default PuTTY configuration](http://poiru.net/2012/01/11/github-authentication-error) solved the issue here. To do so, delete the `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\SimonTatham\PuTTY\Sessions\Default%20Settings` key with regedit.

Comment: Looks like this worked for me too, but I would like to know which settings were set in Putty causing this to fail in tortoise git?

Answer (score 21):

I had the same problem.

I think the problem was that my Putty key was not set in my TortoiseGit Settings. I had to convert my bitbucket repository private key to a putty private key (.ppk file).

This is how I fixed it:

- I downloaded [puttygen.exe](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html)
- I opened puttygen
- I clicked Conversions -> Import key -> (imported my "~/.ssh/id_rsa" key)
- I confirmed my key passphrase
- I clicked "Save private key" and saved the key in my "~/.ssh/" folder
- I went in my TortoiseGit settings : (right click on my master folder) -> TortoiseGit -> Settings -> Git -> Remote -> origin -> Putty key -> ... -> (I added my newly generated putty private key)

And voilà, I was able to push to my origin repository.

Comment: Very good answer. I love these easy step by step lists :) This should be the accepted answer!

Comment: I have id_dsa key in my .ssh folder.
Can't find id_rsa key

Comment: Should I generate it using puttygen ?

Comment: Yes R11G, you should use puttygen to convert your key into a putty private key so TortoiseGit can use it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried all this but it did not work for me. It turns out i had my remote URL wrong:

try this way:  https://github.com/Username/repository-name

instead of this:   git@github.com:Username/repository-name.git

Answer (score 0):

Try this Example. This is the solution to your problem
https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+SSH+for+Mercurial

Answer (score -1):

Push from the command line and see if you get the same problem. If you do, it's most likely a public key issue.

```
SSH -vvvv yourproject.unfuddle.com
```

To see what key is bring presented. You can manipulate what public keys are used by tailoring your `.ssh/conf` file.

Hope this helps.